# Count clicks of my <DIV>

Tags: html, facebook, click, counter

I want to add how many people have successfully clicked my facebook like plugin on different websites. For example,

Website 1 - 45 people clicked the facebook plugin (Like button)
Website 2 - 10 people clicked the facebook plugin (Like button)
& etc.

PS. Not the total likes of my facebook page but the plugin itself only.

Comment: You could write a simple event handler that counts the number of clicks and saves to your server. Have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Take a look into this to improve your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @NisargShah it does not work when i insert the facebook plugin. the counter does not work with

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the like event with `FB.Events.subscribe`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/